# Как убрать автофокус в elRTE?

Tags: веб-программирование, ide, html, javascript

Если вдруг кто пользовался elRTE... Как убрать автофокус (автоматическую установку курсора) у этого редактора при загрузке страницы?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался. Убрать никак, но можно поставить другой после загрузки.

```
<body onLoad="document.getElementById('header').focus();">
```